# Angular 7 http get request issue with non json data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting json data from a url using this:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3200/mydata').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And the about is return json so it's working ok.

But now I also have a url that return some html

And I try:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3200/nonjson').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Http failure during parsing ...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should specify then the response type (**You had a parsing error since `JSON` is default requested type** ):

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3200/nonjson', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

See [**official doc**](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).